# Should expired duplicate closure comments remain?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, duplicate-questions

I have voted to close the question [How to disable highlight on a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816080/how-to-disable-highlight-on-a-image) as a duplicate. From the comments, I can see that another user flagged it as a duplicate of the same question back in 2016.

I presume that other user's closure flag has expired, since a number of years have passed and on the closure pop up, it only shows '1' next to duplicate:

[image]

When I voted to close the question, it upvoted the other user's comment.

Is it worth the expired duplicate comment remaining, and my subsequent duplicate flag upvoting the expired duplicate flag comment?

It seems to give the wrong impression that it currently has two closure votes.

Comment: Given that anyone could have upvoted that comment, I don't see how anyone would have that impression, the number of close votes a question has is displayed in a different location.  The number of votes a canned comment has no relation to the number of close votes a question might have.

Comment: Why would you ever consider a link to another possible solution not be kept? Lots of people have nuanced variations on similar issues

Answer (score 13):

It doesn't give that impression at all. The close pop-up dialog always tells you precisely how many currently active close votes there are.

Retaining the comment is useful, because even if a question doesn't obtain enough close votes to actually get closed, the reference to the proposed duplicate may still be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes the closure process fails us and a real duplicate doesn’t get closed.

Sometimes a question seems like a duplicate for one reason or another but isn’t.

In either of these cases, it can be helpful for people looking for answers to be able to read the linked question. And in the case of a legitimate duplicate, having the old comment there helps future close voters.

You simply can’t rely on the score (or existence) of a duplicate comment to indicate the number of duplicate close votes (that’s why the number is shown in the close dialog). The duplicate comment will be created/upvoted if a < 2k user flags it as a duplicate, and can also be upvoted like any other comment without taking any additional actions.